# Phpunit, Dependency Injection, test stubs: inject mock, or anonymus object?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have some doubt what to inject. Given this code:

```
class A
{
    public function getSomething()
    {
        return 'something';
    }
}

class TestMe
{
    /**
     * @var A
     */
    private $a;

    public function __construct($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function greetings()
    {
        return 'Hello, '.$this->a->getSomething();
    }
}
```

my test A:

```
function testA()
{
    $a = new class() {
        public function getSomething()
        {
            return 'aAnonimus';
        }
    };

    $sut = new TestMe($a);

    $this->assertEquals($sut->greetings(), 'Hello, aAnonimus');
}
```

testB, same but with mock:

```
function testA()
{
    $a = $this->createMock(A::class);
    $a->method('getSomething')->willReturn('bMockery');

    $sut = new TestMe($a);

    $this->assertEquals($sut->greetings(), 'Hello, bMockery');
}
```

in the first test I simply inject a plain object.
But the second its more Phpunit's way: using mocked objects.

Question is, for long period which one wins? I find the first more conviement, and for the 2nd test, you have to know the class name of dependency (otherwise you cant create a mock)

Comment: and what's wrong for anyone "to know the class name of dependency"?

Comment: because if it changes, the test should too.

Comment: hmm... how about a different view: you need changes for some dependency -> you set it up in test case -> you change it in source code? I mean 2 points: a) you don't usually use random dependencies in your classes, do you?  you need smth specific, expectable and sort of reliable; b) and yes, source code and test code are in some kind of correlation, they follow each other (nobody wants irrelevant tests). And technically think about typehinted dependencies -- you would need to extend anonymous class anyway what is === 'know the class name'.

Comment: The phpunit way is definitely the best option in the long run. You can add `expects` to it to make sure it is actually called. You can add `with` to it to make sure it's being called with the right variables. You can use `willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls` to make it return different values if the function gets called multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the longterm, it's better the second way because it's better to have type hint in the constructor which will not allow you to provide a simple object.
Also when we are talking about UnitTests you should test a certain class without depending on 3rd party libraries or other services logic. So the best way is to use mocks for all of the services which are part of the tested class